# Finding MLE for $\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$

Tags: self-study, estimation, negative-binomial-distribution

Let $Z_1, Z_2,... Z_n \sim Ber(\theta)$

Let $X$ be the number of trials **before** the 1st success. So $X \sim NB(1,\theta)$

First, I was asked to find an MLE of $\theta$ based on $X$. I did this by going through the MLE procedure for a single rv $X$ which yielded my estimator $\frac{1}{x}$.

Next, I was asked to find the MLE for $f(\theta)=\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$. For this, I used the invariance property of MLEs so since $\frac{1}{x}$ estimates $\theta$, the estimator for $f(\theta)=\frac{1}{x-1}$. My problem with this estimator is that it is undefined when $x=1$.

Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: what are $Z$'s here for? - just curious :-)

Comment: Since $X$ can take on value $0$ with positive probability, your estimator is not very useful when the very first trial resulted in a success and so $x = 0$.   Try again.

Comment: @Math-fun it's there in order for me to figure out that X is NB. The problem did not spell that detail out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial derivation of the MLE of $\theta$ is incorrect, and that affects all that follows.  $p(x|\theta) \propto \theta(1-\theta)^x$, so the likelihood function is:

$l(\theta) = \theta(1-\theta)^x$

Working with the log likelihood instead, valid since the log is a monotonic transform, gives us:

$\log l(\theta) = \log \theta + x \log (1-\theta)$

with derivative:

$\frac{\text{d}\log l(\theta)}{\text{d}\theta} = \frac{1}{\theta} -\frac{x}{(1-\theta)}$

Setting the derivative equal to 0, skipping a bit of intermediate algebra on the way, gives:

$(1-\theta) = x\theta$

which rearranges to:

$\theta = \frac{1}{x+1}$

rather than $\theta = 1/x$.

This makes intuitive sense, as you actually have $x+1$ observations, one of which is a success and $x$ of which are failures, so it's natural to suspect that the estimated probability of success should be $1/(x+1)$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Where I went wrong is with the pmf of the NB where I used $\theta(1-\theta)^{x-1}$ I am a bit confused by this because both forms seem to appear on materials online. What is the difference between them so I would know which to use?

Comment: As it happens, there are lots of slightly different ways of defining it!  In many cases, the definition is of the number of successes before the first (or $k^{th}$) failure, in which case $\theta$ and $1-\theta$ get switched in the above formula.  If you define it this way, and further modify the definition to be the number of trials (not number of successes) given 1 (or $k$) successes, then you get the $-1$ (or $-k$) in there.  Intuitively, this adjusts for the fact that the number of trials has to be $\geq$ 1 (or $k$), as it's just the number of failures + the nonrandom number of successes.